# Collection is not defined (but rest is OK)

Tags: meteor

THIS is not a duplicate question!

In my app, I have collections directory (in project root) with files (every file corresponds to one collection). My tempates (in client/templates/...), of course, use collections. Everything perfect with one small exception. One of my collections is undefined but the rest is ok. Every collection is defined in the same directory and in the same directory level. Where is the problem?

EDIT: I tryed inserting collections inside lib. Not works. I tryed deep nesting. Not works.

EDIT: Tell me, why I have 2 downvotes. Downvotes are for good for nothing questions, this question may help in future another Meteor users. So, why are you downvoting this quetion?

Comment: Are you using `Meteor.isServer` in your `collections` folder? I suggest adding to your question: the code from `collections` declaring the collection that fails, the code from `client` querying the collection, the specific error message you are getting.

Comment: @Seraph, Just in case nest collections dir few times. Move it from `/collections` to `/_/_/_/collections`.  Just to make sure it is loaded first. My experience is that it is best to create local package for collections - as then you will not have any problem with loading order.

Comment: @BraveKenny No, it's not. Why??? Collections are global ... I can't post any code, it's closed source and you see nothing. It's the same as other collections, but this one is undefined. Specific error message is in tittle ...

Comment: make sure that you create your collection inside `lib` directory in project root

Answer (score 0):

Bug has interesting roots. I'm using fedora 21, and in theese times, Chrome has bug which causes complete freeze (1-5 hours). This bug has many Linux distributions. After I restarted chrome after freeze, the error vanished. So, the result is that Chrome has two bugs instead of one :)

EDIT: No. It's premature conclusion. It works only for a while but then it failed again. In Chrome and in Firefox too. I'm really confused.